# How to specify Java version for Gradle buildSrc?

Tags: java, gradle

My build.gradle uses a custom task, which I defined in the buildSrc/src/main/java directory using Java 11. Now, I need to build on a different machine which only has Java 8 installed, so the Gradle build cannot even configure because it complains of errors in my custom task. Of course, I could install Java 11 in my home directory (since I don't have root privileges on this machine) and run Gradle with a custom JAVA_HOME, but is there a way that Gradle could automate this process. That is, could I somehow declare the Java version required for buildSrc so that Gradle will download and use that version?

[Gradle toolchains](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/toolchains.html) looks somewhat promising, but it is not obvious how this should be applied to buildSrc.

Comment: I don't think Gradle will download JDKs. Can you set the source level in `buildSrc/build.gradle` to 8?

Comment: I have tried changing the Java version with Gradle toolchains with `java.toolchain.languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(11)`, and I've also tried changing it with `sourceCompatibility = '11'`, but neither seem to apply to buildSrc.

Comment: Gradle can be wrapped to download itself but you can't tell gradle to be java fluent. Your project has a fixed target and you can build it on 11 and then on 8 if everything is compatible. That's your job as developer to be compatible of set up fixed versions/environments

Comment: Too bad, it sounds like the answer is "no". I was able to compile buildSrc with Java 11, but then I get this error: `CustomTask has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0`.